# Mostrar infowindow automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html5

Quisiera que me ayuden a quitar el `click` de mi `infowindow` y me muestre automáticamente

```
var imformo2='<h1>SITIO ARQUEOLOGICO LAS JUNTAS</h1>'+'<h3>PROVINCIA DE BAGUA</h3>'+
    '<img src="jean.jpg" hegth="200px" width="300px"></img>';

    var Ventant2= new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content:imformo2});

    var myLatlng = {lat: -5.644392, lng: -78.551944};
    var punte2 = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Sitio arqueologico de Las Juntas-Bagua'
        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(punte2, 'click', function(){Ventant2.open(map,punte2);});
```

Comment: Hola jean, sería bueno que pasearas un poco por [ask] y formatearas mejor tu pregunta. De lo contrario esto no es contestable

Answer (score 0):

En lugar del evento click, utiliza el evento domready. No he podido comprobarlo por la falta del apykey ahora mismo, pero por lo que he leído debería funcionarte.

```
infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function() {
      // whatever you want to do once the DOM is ready
});
```